# Error number 1064 in CodeIgniter query database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

I need some help about this tutorial. I encountered an Error related to the database error 1064.

It states:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'NOT NULL, last_activity INT(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, user_data text NO'` at line 4

```
CREATE TABLE `ci_sessions` (
    session_id VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent VARCHAR(120) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
    last_activity INT(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `session_id` (`session_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

HERE is the tutorials query :

```
public function up() {
        $fields = array (
            'session_id VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT \'0\' NOT NULL',
            'ip_address VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT \'0\' NOT NULL',
            'user_agent VARCHAR(120) DEFAULT NOT NULL',
            'last_activity INT(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL',
            'user_data text NOT NULL'
        );

        $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
        $this->dbforge->add_key('session_id', TRUE);
        $this->dbforge->create_table('ci_sessions');
        $this->db->query('ALTER TABLE `ci_sessions` ADD KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)');
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing the default value for the `user_agent` column?

Comment: what do you mean sir?

Comment: I mean `'user_agent VARCHAR(120) DEFAULT XXX NOT NULL',` instead of your `'user_agent VARCHAR(120) DEFAULT NOT NULL',`. The XXX. Like in the other columns.

Comment: mygoshhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.. so sorry.. thx sir..  :'( sorry sorry sorry.. THANKS VERY MUCH.

Comment: No problem. That was easy :-).

Comment: can you please answer not in the comment. For me to mark Green Check for the correct answer. Thank you very much sir

Comment: Oh, that's very kind of you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the actual default *value* for the `user_agent` column in the `$fields` array.

Change this

```
$fields = array (
    ...
    'user_agent VARCHAR(120) DEFAULT NOT NULL',
    ...
);
```

to this

```
$fields = array (
    ...
    'user_agent VARCHAR(120) DEFAULT \'0\' NOT NULL',
    ...
);
```

or some other reasonable default value, like with the other columns.